# mongo docker container cannot access localhost data

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I started building a POC for an application and it generated a lot of useful data in mongodb which was hosted on *localhost*. I connected to that data using mongoshell and MongoDb Compass.

Recently, I split the monolith application into a set of microservices and introduce docker into it. Also added mongo in *docker-compose* as a dependency. All the microservices and mongo container were able to start and run the logic.

However the application did not find any reference of old data as the hosted mongodb container was missing the localhost collections. It is behaving like a fresh database. I have not made any change with reference to ipBinding

The mongodb connection file in application points to the mongodb container(previously it was `mongodb://localhost:27017/${dbName}`).

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo'
    ports:
       - "27017:27017"

  some-api:
    build: ./some-api
    ports:
      - 8005:8105
```

Mongodb connection file:

```
        const url = `mongodb://mongo:27017/${dbName}`;

        const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

So I want help with 3 questions:

1. How does the mongo container use localhost data or point to that data?
2. How should I preserve the data generated from docker containers when the container shuts-down and still see that on localhost mongo server?
3. As mongo container runs on a Ip, can I use that ip to connect it using Mongo Compass once the container is up and running?

Thanks!

Comment: When using MongoDB with docker you need to think about data persistence.  In some cases you might not care if the data is deleted when a container is deleted.  In other cases you may want to delete the container and spin up a new one, but have the old data retained.  If this is the case then persistent storage is required.

Comment: You cannot in general use the Docker-private IP addresses.

Comment: @DavidMaze You mean I cannot use docker private Ip address to login using compass?

Comment: No.  Of particular note, it does not work from other hosts, and it does not work on non-Linux hosts.  You must publish a port and use that port and the host’s IP address, or use the inter-container DNS system within the same host’s Docker environment.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo container does not use your localhost data by default (the value of containerization is that everything is separate), but you can link it to the data using [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). You'll have to know where your local mongo files are, and where they're expected to be in the container's operating system, and may need to use the same storage engine locally and in the container.

Your docker-compose would then look something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo'
    volumes:
      - "/local/path/to/mongo/files/:/container/path/to/mongo/files/"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  some-api:
    build: ./some-api
    ports:
      - 8005:8105
```

Comment: I checked the local storage for mongodb on my machine, it is at /data/db. Not sure about container path. But I added volumes as `- "./data/db:/data/db"  `, rebuilt and started the container fresh. If I take a shell to mongo container and inspect it still doesn't show localhost collections.

Comment: `./data/db` is not the same as `/data/db`, so you'll probably need to use `/data/db/:/data/db`. Mongo's entry in the Docker hub has some additional info about storage that might come in handy: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Answer (score 0):

All containers are an isolated world from your host server, therefore they have no access to any data in your host.

You can bypass this using linked volumes (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes), you may also need to check mongo image documentation (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo PS.: Go for 'Where to Store Data' section)

After creating your volume, you can point it to your old data, but be careful, you need to use the same version of mongo so your data won't be corrupted.

Comment: I added volume as `"./data/db:/data/db"`. But that didn't work. So I am thinking to copy that data manually. Once data is copied to container mongo server, it should persist between shutdown and restart, right, I mean if I remove container, that image and then rebuild + start again, I should still get to that data  ?

Comment: If it is a volume it will persist across container recreation.